# Set-builder notation for a set that is either the complex or the real set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $F$ is either the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, that is, if $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\mathbb{C}$, is it correct to write $F=\{x:x\in\mathbb{R} \vee x\in\mathbb{C} \}$ ?

Comment: It is certainly correct to write, as you have done, "$F=\Bbb R$ or $F=\Bbb C$".

Comment: What you wrote is the definition of the union of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. But since $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$, $F = \mathbb C$. That's not what you want. How about just writing $F = \mathbb R \lor F = \mathbb C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote down is $F = \mathbb{R} \cup \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}$.

But I think you meant to write $F \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$.